# Pagination on an Advanced Custom Fields Repeater Stopped Working

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

Not sure if this was since upgrading to PHP 7.2 or the latest WordPress version but the following code used to allow me to add pagination for repeater values. Now what seems to happen is that the page just reloads the page. The pagination link shows as `/example/2/`, this used to load the page but now it is just reloading `example`.

Any ideas?

```
<?php
/* 
 * Paginatation on Advanced Custom Fields Repeater
 */

 if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $page = get_query_var('paged');
 } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $page = get_query_var('page');
 } else {
    $page = 1;
 }

// Variables
$row              = 0;
$images_per_page  = 10; // How many images to display on each page
$images           = get_field( 'image_gallery' );
$total            = count( $images );
$pages            = ceil( $total / $images_per_page );
$min              = ( ( $page * $images_per_page ) - $images_per_page ) + 1;
$max              = ( $min + $images_per_page ) - 1;

// ACF Loop
if( have_rows( 'image_gallery' ) ) : ?>

<?php while( have_rows( 'image_gallery' ) ): the_row();

    $row++;

    // Ignore this image if $row is lower than $min
    if($row < $min) { continue; }

    // Stop loop completely if $row is higher than $max
    if($row > $max) { break; } ?>

<?php $img_obj = get_sub_field( 'image' ); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $img_obj['sizes']['large']; ?>">
        <img src ="<?php echo $img_obj['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt= "Your ALT Tag" />
    </a>

<?php endwhile;

  // Pagination
  echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => get_permalink() . '%#%' . '/',
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => $page,
    'total' => $pages
  ) );
  ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <p>No images found</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug tracker after 5.5:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/50976#comment:7

You might check some of the solutions there. It seems to be an issue with the query var "page" which is reserved in WordPress core, since it normally uses ?p and ?page to redirect to a certain page.

So you might use something else.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is still struggling with this, here is how I solved it after most of the solutions didn't worked properly:

```
$page = 1; //right after get_header();
global $wp_query;

$wp_query->is_paged = 1;
if ( isset( $_GET['chapter'] ) ) {
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] = $_GET['chapter'];    
}

if( get_query_var('paged') ) {
  $page = get_query_var( 'paged' );
}
```

and for paginate_links I used this

```
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => get_permalink() . '?chapter=%#%',
'current' => $page,
'total' => $pages
) );
```

Not the best solution, but worked for me.